# Which sensor i can use to transmit some values from Arduino Uno to phone using bluetooth?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I want to transmit some values from arduino uno to my phone using bluetooth.
Which sensor i can use?I want to see some options because i'm a little bit uncertain.Thanks to all which can give me an advice !  :)

Comment: So you want to know how to send a text file from the arduino to the phone?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a sensor, its a module. A quite popular module is the [HC-05](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00INWZRNC). It's a very simple to use module with a lot of support by the community. Cheap and great for projects.